# Javascript FSM Possibilities / Idea

Tags: javascript, fsm

So I have been making stuff in Unity3D and decided to try an extension called Playmaker.  Basically is uses a FSM (Finite State Machine) to design the flow of states and events.  You can drag an event to a different state to trigger another state of events, etc.  (Reference : http://www.hutonggames.com/features.html) 
NOTE : The actual product I linked has nothing to do with the idea I want to try and build.  Just a reference.

Well I would love to be able to do something simliar in Javascript.  I think I have some of the logic down but I'm thinking more about User Experience.  I want a user to be able to create an FSM with my logic in the browser using Javascript.

I'm not asking for anyone to code this for me or anything as I am experienced enough in javascript to do the bulk of it.  I was thinking more about the way you can drag one event to another and it creates a visual arrow showing the user what events are connected.  If you look at the first tutorial on the referenced link I provided you will understand what I mean.  The arrow length and curves would be dynamic.  Possibly be able to drag around states to re organize the layout of the states.  This would obviously change the way the arrows pointed as well.

I hope that all made sense.

Ideas?  Pointers?  Maybe someone has done something like this already?  I did find one Javascript State Machine but it generates once, doesn't allow users to move anything, the event dragging to another state is very important.

Comment: So you want to create a UI, something like a node graph with draggable handles, that represents a state machine?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  Probably a better description than I could come up with

Comment: Tyler, it's ridiculous, but I have had the exact same experience with FSMs.  Are you still looking into this?  I mean yeah, the hardcore coders will hate FSM (or will they?), but just as jQuery abstracts away a TON javascript FSMs could do the same.